# Error code element " " undefined [XHTML 1.0 Strict]

Tags: css, xhtml, message, nav

I'm using Dreamweaver to code a simple website index page.  When I run the W3 Validator I am getting the following error messages that I cannot solve:
       element "header" underfined[XHTML 1.0 Strict]
       element "nav" undefined[XHTML 1.0 Strict]

Here is my HTML/CSS code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/
xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<meta name="description" content="Yahoo Web Hosting Review and PHP Tutorial"/>
<meta name="keywords" content="Web,Hosting,Yahoo,PHP, configuration, advantages, disadvantages,
how to, instructions"/>
<title>Yahoo Web Hosting Reviews and Tutorial</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css"/>

</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
<div id="header">
<header>Yahoo Web Hosting Reviews and PHP Tutorial</header>
</div>
<nav>
<a href="../index.html">Home</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a 
href="../PHP.html">PHP</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="../Reviews.html">Reviews</a></nav>
</div>
<div class="main-content">
<h1>Yahoo Web Hosting</h1>
<p class="definition">Is it a good fit for you?</p>
<h2>PHP Configuration How-To</h2></div>
<div id="footer">
<div class="footer-content">Copyright 2014 John Doe. All rights reserved.</div>

</div></body>
</html>
```

CSS Code:

```
#header {
    background-color: #000;
    border-top-color: #6CF;
    border-right-color: #6CF;
    border-bottom-color: #6CF;
    border-left-color: #6CF;
    height: 120px;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    top: auto;
    font-family: Cambria, "Hoefler Text", "Liberation Serif", Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: xx-large;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.main-content {
    text-align: center;
    height: 500px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 100px;
}
.footer-content {
    font-family: Cambria, "Hoefler Text", "Liberation Serif", Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
    font-size: 90%;
    background-color: #6CF;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: auto;
}
.container {
    background-color: #6CF;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    height: auto;
    color: #000;
}
.content {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 500px;
}
#footer {
    background-color: #6CF;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    bottom: 0px;
}
h1 {
    font-family: Cambria, "Hoefler Text", "Liberation Serif", Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #FFF;
}
#nav {
    font-family: Cambria, "Hoefler Text", "Liberation Serif", Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-weight: bolder;
    color: #000;
    text-align: left;
    height: 50px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    width: auto;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.  I'm new to this but I've racked my brain trying to understand this issue.

Comment: In addition to the answers, you also have `#nav` in the CSS without a corresponding `id="nav"` in the XHTML. Ditto with `#header`. Be sure to fix that. Also, don't use `&nbsp;` for layout.

Answer (score 3):

header element is part of the HTML 5 doctype hence the error.
http://html5doctor.com/the-header-element/
So is nav.

This is valid XHTML since you use xhtml1-strict.

```
 <div class="container">
   <div id="header">
   Yahoo Web Hosting Reviews and PHP Tutorial
   </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Like @JohanVandenRym answered, `header` and `nav` are parts of `HTML5`. As an alternative solution you can change your `doctype` to HTML5.

use this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
```

instead of :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

**Update :**

If you try to keep the `doctype` as strict XHTML. You should change `header` and `nav` with `div`.

```
<div id="header">
  <div>Yahoo Web Hosting Reviews and PHP Tutorial</div>
</div>

<div id="nav">
  <a href="../index.html">Home</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="../PHP.html">PHP</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="../Reviews.html">Reviews</a>
</div>
```

Comment: According to the instructions I have been given, I am to use strict XHTML.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I hadn't seen the link to the tutorial above.  Thanks...it's perfect, just what I needed.  Thanks guys for your help!!